# How can I programmatically pipe a QuickTime movie into a Quartz Composer input?

Tags: objective-c, macos, quicktime, qtkit, quartz-composer

I'm working on an app that applies Quartz Composer effects to QuickTime movies.  Think Photo Booth, except with a QuickTime movie for the input, not a camera.  Currently, I am loading a quicktime movie as a `QTMovie` object, then have an `NSTimer` firing 30 times a second.  At some point I'll switch to a `CVDisplayLink`, but `NSTimer` is okay for now.  Every time the `NSTimer` fires, the app grabs one frame of the quicktime movie as an `NSImage` and passes it to one of the `QCRenderer`'s image inputs.  This works, but is **extremely** slow.  I've tried pulling frames from the movie in all of the formats that `[QTMovie frameImageAtTime:withAttributes:error:]` supports. They are all either really slow, or don't work at all.

I'm assuming that the slowness is caused by moving the image data to main memory, then moving it back for QC to work on it.

Unfortunately, using QC's QuickTime movie patch is out of the question for this project, as I need more control of movie playback than that provides.  So the question is, how can I move QuickTime movie images into my QCRenderer without leaving VRAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [v002 Movie Player](http://v002.info/?page_id=13) QCPlugin which is open source. Anyway, what more controls do you have exactly?

Comment: Wow, yeah, that plugin gives you much more control over movie playback in a Quartz composition.  I took a look at the source and it seems the answer to my question revolves around spawning a separate process to play the movie, then using `IOSurface` to share the image data with the first process.

Comment: IOSurface in this cause added by 64-bit compatibility, because QTKit is 32-bit only. You can still do a lot of things with the stock QC Movie Importer patch, if you use the external timebase option.

For an example, download CoGe - http://cogevj.hu - and check the Movie Player modules.